# Static and non-static multithreading

Tags: java

Suppose i have a class with both static and non-static synchronized methods and a thread tries to access the static method. Thus the lock will be acquired on the class. Now my question is, if another thread simultaneously tries to access the non-static method, will it be able to access it or not?

Comment: It will be able to access it if no other thread is calling the same method (or other synchronized) on the same object. Your best bet is trying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each class in Java gets a single `Class<YourClass>` instance at run time. When you synchronize on a class or on a `static` method, you are synchronizing on that instance.

```
public static synchronized void doSomething() {}
// or explicit
synchronized (YourClass.class) {}
```

Either of these would block, if a `Thread` was in the other, because `YourClass.class` returns the same `Class<YourClass>` instance that the synchronized method is using.

In case of an instance method

```
public synchronized void doOther() {}
// or explicit
synchronized (instance)
```

calling `doOther()` implicitly executes

```
synchronized (this)
```

around the method.

In the `static` case, you're `synchronizing` on a `Class` instance. In the `instance` case, you're `synchronizing` on an instance of your class. Those are two different monitors. Because they are different monitors, having on `Thread` execute `static doSomething()` won't block another `Thread` executing instance `doOther()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Static synchronized method locked on class object
e.g. for MyClass class its MyClass.class
while instance synchronized method locks on current instance of Object denoted by “this” keyword in Java.

> Since both of these object are different they have different lock so while one thread is executing static synchronized method , other thread in java doesn’t need to wait for that thread to return instead it will acquire separate lock denoted byte.

Read more [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/mixing-static-and-non-static.html)